# My app always force close when i start it, after i add some code for ViewPageAdapter

Tags: android

Below is the stack trace from Logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.mobil, PID: 15703
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mobil/com.example.mobil.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
            at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.mobil.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:47)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Your tabLayout variable is null. Post related code here. Otherwise no one would be able to help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)